# box shadow on figure element getting skewed due to root margin

Tags: html, css

I've provided a `box-shadow` on `figure` element. But, the image is appearing skewed due to the `*{margin:10px}` that I've given. Is there any way that I can still maintain this margin and be able to land the box shadow just on the figure element?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="drop.css"
>

</head>
<body>

    <section id="pics">
        <figure
            id="pic1"
            class="pictures"
        >
            <img
                alt="figure1"
                src="http://b-i.forbesimg.com/kellyclay/files/2013/12/glass.jpg"
                title="pic1"
            >
            <figcaption class="figuredetails">Fig1</figcaption>

        </figure>


        <figure
            id="pic2"
            class="pictures"
        >
            <img
                alt="figure2"
                src="http://glass-apps.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/google-glass1.jpg"
                title="pic2"
            >
            <figcaption class="figuredetails">Fig2</figcaption>

        </figure>
    </section>
    <section id="content">
    <p>hello</p>
    </section>
</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
*{
    margin: 10px;
    /* padding: 10px; */

}


#pics{

    width:100%;
    padding: 50px 50px;
} 

.pictures{
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.pictures:before{
    border:5px solid black;
}
.pictures:after{
    border:5px solid black;
}


.pictures img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border: 2px solid;

    border-color: #ff0000;



}

/* #pic1{

    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); IE 9
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); Chrome, Safari, Opera
    transform: rotate(30deg);
} */


#pic2{
    padding-left: 50px;
}

#content{
    clear: both;
}

.pictures > .figuredetails{
    color: red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

The JSfiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5kgh8/

Comment: What output do you exactly want.Can you just show us an image?

Comment: I cant show the image. I just want that the image should come only inside the box which is giving a shadow.

Comment: Anything like this : http://jsfiddle.net/r83P7/ ?

Comment: Yes. But, I want to maintain the margin and still want the other pic

Answer (score 0):

As your first comments says that you want the pictures to be displayed inside shadow box so the only thing you need to do is just remove

```
#pic2{
padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Also i do not find any use of

```
*{
   margin: 10px;
   /* padding: 10px; */
}
```

Remove that as well.

Result: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kgh8/2/)

Comment: Actually, the `padding-left` in `#pic2` is to take care of the rotation of pic1 that I'm going to do and to give pic2 some space after pic1. Also, the `margin` is used so that all the content starts after some space on the left e.g. the facebook timeline is always some distance from the left